# Equivalent SecurityAlgorithmSuite in .Net Core

Tags: .net-core, wcf-binding, equivalent, rsa-sha256

I am migrating a project from .Net framework 4.8 to .Net Core 3.1.

The problem is that this Basic256 algorithm is not compatible with Net Core

```
SecurityAlgorithmSuite.Basic256Sha256Rsa15
```

Do you know any equivalent libraries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These security algorithms are used to ensure the security of the WCF message layer. As far as I know, the WCF server cannot be created in `DotNet Core`, and the WCF client based on `DotNet Core` is only a compatible solution, especially the message layer security has not been implemented, let alone these algorithms.
Please refer to the official repository and discussion.
https://github.com/dotnet/wcf
[https://github.com/dotnet/wcf/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=SecurityAlgorithmSuite+](https://github.com/dotnet/wcf/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=SecurityAlgorithmSuite%20)
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.